# One pixel fill, with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mapping, pixel

This might be a somewhat stupid question, but...is it possible to fill an HTML canvas element, pixel by pixel, depending on where a user clicks?

I want to have a blank canvas, that users will click one pixel at a time, which will fill a color, and enter that user/pixel into a database.

How would this be done?
How can I know what pixel, what user clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set each canvas pixel individually based on mouse-clicks.

Here's how you set an individual pixel using context.getImageData and context.putImageData:

```
    function setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue) {
        pixPos=( (~~x) + (~~y)) * 4;
        var pxData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
            pxData.data[0]=red;
            pxData.data[1]=green;
            pxData.data[2]=blue;
            pxData.data[3]=255;
            ctx.putImageData(pxData,x,y);
    }
```

And you get the X/Y position of the mouse click by adding an event listener like this:

```
    // get the position of the canvas relative to the web page
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // tell the browser to send you mouse down events
    // Here I use jquery -- be sure to add jquery or just do addEventListener instead
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

    // handle the mousedown events that the browser sends you
    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      setPixel(mouseX,mouseY,red,green,blue);
    }
```

Here's code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wtStf/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var red=255;
    var green=0;
    var blue=0;

    function setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue) {
        pixPos=( (~~x) + (~~y)) * 4;
        var pxData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
            pxData.data[0]=red;
            pxData.data[1]=green;
            pxData.data[2]=blue;
            pxData.data[3]=255;
            ctx.putImageData(pxData,x,y);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      setPixel(mouseX,mouseY,red,green,blue);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Edited for additional question]**

You can easily modify the code to set blocks of pixels like this:

```
var blockWidth=25;
var blockHeight=25;

function setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue) {
    pixPos=( (~~x) + (~~y)) * 4;
    var pxData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,blockWidth,blockHeight);
    for(var n=0;n<blockWidth*blockHeight;n++){
        pxData.data[n*4+0]=red;
        pxData.data[n*4+1]=green;
        pxData.data[n*4+2]=blue;
        pxData.data[n*4+3]=255;
    }
        ctx.putImageData(pxData,x,y);
}
```

Comment: Wow!! that was fast, and extremely concise and helpful!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: 2 more questions for you mark....How can I stop someone from selecting the same pixel??  (I guess I can do an ajax call to check if its already in the database ??)  Also how can I alter this, so that its a 25x25 "pixel" instead of 1x1 (or any other size for that matter)  I apologize for my naiveity.

Comment: Setting blocks of pixels is easy (see my edited answer above).  About not "double-setting": a new-block and an already-set-block might incompletely overlap.  In that case, would you allow the selection?  BTW, to check if a block was already set, I wouldn't go all the way back to the database, I would just look on the canvas and see if the block was already set (faster/more efficient) ;)

Comment: But what if there are multiple users all placing pixels at the same time...wouldn't I need to keep track of them, and keep the canvas up-todate by constantly refreshing with the latest database values?  How would I draw the canvas with every update? How would that work.  Just a loop, that loops through the values, and places them again one by one?

Comment: Oops! I didn't know the game was multi-user. Yep, in that event you'll want to check the DB for everything.  As far as your update logic goes: assign every block a number and give every user an array which lists the filled blocks.  If you will need high frequency updates, you might want to check out websockets which allows async/continuous connections to the server.

Comment: To answer this question......"About not "double-setting": a new-block and an already-set-block might incompletely overlap. In that case, would you allow the selection?"  No I don't want to allow the selection.  So for instance imagine a grid.  If the user clicks somewhere it places a block, but that block must adhere to the grid.  So if he clicks a bit above it will 'snap' into the next block, if you know what I mean.  This way there is no overlapping, and I can easily identify which users blocks are where.....how would I only allow grid placement as opposed to free placement.

Comment: you mentioned websockets for async/continuouts connections....do you have any links/tutorials I can look at that will help me on that.  And does the fact Im using a PHP framework (laravel), limit what Im able to do with websockets?

Comment: Websockets are a newly standardized part of html5 so your limitations won’t be with php (plugins are available) but rather with the browsers that currently implement websockets.  (No for IE<10, and no for any android)  I’ve always found netTuts a good souce for info and here’s a fairly good tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

Comment: Wow, that tutorial looks perfect!  Thanks so much!